# 'AttributeError' in linked list in Python

Tags: python, linked-list, duplicates

This code deals with removal of duplicates from a linked list in Python. The problem seems to be in the `remove` function.

```
class Node(object):
  def __init__(self, data = None, next_node = None):
    self.next_node = next_node
    self.data = data

  #get data at that location

  def get_data(self):
    return self.data

  #get next element in linked list

  def get_next(self):
    return self.next_node

  #point to node specified by argument

  def set_next(self, new_next):
    self.next_node = new_next

class LinkedList(object):
  def __init__(self, head = None):
    self.head = head

  #insert element in linked list

  def insert(self, data):
    new_node = Node(data)
    new_node.set_next(self.head)
    self.head = new_node

  #remove duplicates

  def remove(self):
  #point to head
    current = self.head
    previous = None
    removed = False
  #variable to compare the current data with the rest
    new = current
    new = new.get_next()
  #while current is not None
    while current:
      if current.get_data() != new.get_data():
        previous = new
        new = new.get_next()
  #if same data, delete extra node from list
      else:
        removed = True
  #if only one element in list
        if previous is None:
          self.head = new.get_next()
        else:
          previous.set_next(new.get_next())
          new = new.get_next()
  #if 'new' reaches end of list, do this
      if new is None:
        current = current.get_next()
        previous = current
        new = current
        new = new.get_next()
    if not removed:
      print("No duplicates!")

  #print resulting linked list

  def print_result(self):
    current = self.head
    while current:
      print(current.get_data(), end = " ")
      current = current.get_next()
```

(I have ignored the 'function calling' part of the code).

I am getting an attribute error at the first `if` statement after `while current:` (in the `remove` function) saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 64, in <module>
File "python", line 26, in remove
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_data'
```

I can't understand which is `None` and why. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your general approach appears correct, assuming you're OK with an exponential running time, but there are some details that will cause crashes. Here's a couple I spot offhand:

1. If the list is length 1, `if current.get_data() != new.get_data():` will crash because `new` is `None`.
2. These lines:

   ```
   current = current.get_next()
   previous = current
   new = current
   new = new.get_next() # boom!
   ```

   will crash when you reach the end of the list. `current` is the last node and you get the next, which is `None`, and then attempt to `None.get_next()`.

To fix these, proceed through your list one node at a time and check for `None` every time you `next` to avoid crashing. Same goes for unlinking: only unlink one node at a time by keeping `prev` where it is and setting `prev.next_node` and `curr` to `curr.next`, then test if `curr` is `None` before doing anything else.

Here's a simple, working version:

```
def remove(self):
  curr = self.head

  while curr:
    runner = curr.next_node
    prev = curr

    while runner:
      if runner.data == curr.data:
        prev.next_node = runner.next_node
      else:
        prev = runner

      runner = runner.next_node

    curr = curr.next_node
```

The idea is to use `curr` to step through the list node by node. For every node, create a `runner` and `prev` which will iterate through the remainder of the list node by node and unlink any nodes that match `curr`.

There's also a linear approach using a `set` (trading space for speed):

```
def remove_linear(self):
  seen = set()
  curr = self.head
  prev = None

  while curr:
    if curr.data not in seen:
      seen.add(curr.data)
      prev = curr
    else:
      prev.next_node = curr.next_node

    curr = curr.next_node
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/UnfitSaltyGraphics)

A last note: Python generally doesn't use getters and setters; they add verbosity and don't offer any genuine protection, so I omitted them in my code above. Trust your client and use underscore prefixes for "private" variables.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation !! The code is finally working.
Actually this is a question from 'Cracking the coding interview' which asked to solve without using a temporary buffer.
But yeah, my code will be too time-expensive. The linear time is much better.